# Python readline type error an integer is required

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to declare a string value to equal the text of a line number.

File Contents of the file that I am using as the verification table

```
domain1
=============================
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc1
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc2
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc3
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc4
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc5
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc6
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc7
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc8
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc9
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc10
=============================
domain2
=============================
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc1
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc2
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc3
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc4
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc5
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc6
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc7
=============================
domain3
=============================
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc1
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc2
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc3
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc4
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc5
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc6
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc7
=============================
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var = sys.argv[1]

with open('table.txt') as x:
head1 = x.readline()
linenumber = 3
if not var == head1:
for line in x.readlines(linenumber):
print line
linenumber += 1
if x.readlines(linenumber) is ('============================='):
linenumber = 16
break
```

Here is the actual output, that is being seen in the cmd window:

```
"readline type error an integer is required"
```

desired output that I would like to have as a result of the above mentioned chunk of code

```
"xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc1"
```

How would I set this so that I am seeing the correct data?

Comment: The argument to readline doesn't do what you think it does. Check http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline

Answer (score 0):

Could you loop through the lines?

```
for line in x:
    if 'static text' in line:
        print line
```

Comment: I updated my question for you so you could better understand what I'm trying to accomplish. This for loop is fine, but when trying to change to the next line it won't work. P.S. sorry for the bad whitespaces, code writing on this site is picky and it took me 20 minutes to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

`file.readlines(sizehint)` parameter is not a line number, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines).

A file is an iterator over lines in Python: you can use it in a `for`-loop directly or call `next()` to get the next line manually:

```
with open("table.txt") as file:   # open file for reading
    for line in file:             # read it one line at a time
        line = line.strip()       # remove leading/trailing whitespace
        if separator == line:     # found separator e.g., '====..'
            line = next(line, "") # move to the next line
            print line,           # print the line after the separator line
            break                 # exit the loop
```

With your input, it would print:

```
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx pc1
```

If the file is small you could read it into memory as a whole and parse it using string methods such as `.partition()`, `.split()`, using regular expressions (`re` module), etc e.g.:

```
import re

with open("table.txt") as file:
    m = re.search(r"(?m)^=+\s*$\s*(.*)", file.read())
    if m: # found
       print m.group(1)
```

It produces the same output for your input. In general, the result can be different e.g., the regex skips blank lines after the separator line.